# Iterating over Mono<Map<String, String>> and get the desired object

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor

generateComplianceResponse() has a subscribe() which I have commented to highlight it. The issue is I'm not able to populate the locationsMap() in all the cases even though I have kept a flatMap() call. Subscribe() works sometimes but not in all cases and as per spring documentation, subsribe() doesn't always guarantee a result. I want this locationsMap() to be populated in all cases so that my result is consistent.

```
    private Mono<Map<String,String>> locationsMap(){
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("DK", "Denmark");
        map.put("UK", "United Kingdom");
        System.out.println(map);
        return Mono.just(map);
    }

    private void generateComplianceResponse(BOLCompliance complianceResponse) {
        // locationsMap().subscribe();
        locationsMap().flatMap(entry -> {
            Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> set = entry.entrySet();
            set.forEach(e -> {
                if (complianceResponse.getCompliancePort().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase(e.getKey())) {
                    complianceResponse.setCountry(e.getValue());
                }
            });
            return Mono.just(complianceResponse);
        }).doOnNext(System.out::println).subscribe();
    }


public class BOLCompliance {
    private String complianceType;
    private String compliancePort;
    private String country;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `map` operator instead:

```java
Mono.just(locationMap).map(map -> {
  //Map<String, String> to complianceResponse mapping here
  complianceResponse.setCountry(map.get(...));

  return complianceResponse;
});
```

`flatmap` is for asynchronous 1-to-N transformations.

**Edit**

As I said above, you should use `map` instead of `flatmap`. You could also, fetch it as a plain Map:

```
private Map<String,String> locationsMap() {
//...
```

Most importantly, **don't** `subscribe()` by yourself, return the subscription to the caller instead:

```java
private Mono<BOLCompliance> generateComplianceResponse(BOLCompliance complianceResponse) {
//...
```

Comment: map() also doesnt work for me, I'm trying to iterate over this Mono<Map<String,String>> and get the single matching object

Comment: @MiraDevi You can iterate the `Map<String, String>` instance inside the `map` operator and map it to `complianceResponse`. I've updated that answer to make it more clear.

Comment: I have added the complete code which should compile in your system, please provide a solution if possible. Currently, code is inconsistent with the result due to reactive calls not being wrapped properly

Comment: @MiraDevi edit made

Comment: actually locationMap(), I'm populating from redis cache and from there I'm getting it as a Mono so can't change it to normal object and even the other methods are more complex and chained with others, here i have given more simple example so that I can get appropriate help from people. I tried with map() also but it didn't work. Could you please execute the above question in your system and see, it's not giving result as per your solution provided. Also, please dont change the signature of any method

Comment: @MiraDevi You will never see the desired result if you subscribe by yourself. You have to return the subscription. This is the rule.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the consistent result with block().
But I remember in the past, this block() used to give error: block()/blockfirst()/blocklast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread. But for this piece of code its not giving any

```
private void generateComplianceResponse(BOLCompliance complianceResponse, BOLReference bill) {
        complianceResponse.setStatus(bill.getStatus()!=null?bill.getStatus():null);
        complianceResponse.setErrorDetails(bill.getErrorDetails());
        getCustomsStatus(complianceResponse, bill);
        getComplianceCountry(complianceResponse).block();
    }
    
    private Mono<BOLCompliance> getComplianceCountry(BOLCompliance complianceResponse) {
        
        return locationMap().flatMap(entry -> {
        
        Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> set = entry.entrySet();
         set.forEach(e -> {
                if (complianceResponse.getCompliancePort().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase(e.getKey())) {
                    complianceResponse.setCountry(e.getValue());
                }
            });
            return Mono.just(complianceResponse);
        });
    }
```