# Reactive method not giving consistent result even with flatMap()

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor

generateComplianceResponse() has a subscribe() which I have commented to highlight it. The issue is I'm not able to populate the locationsMap() in all the cases even though I have kept a flatMap() call. Subscribe() works sometimes but not in all cases and as per spring documentation, subsribe() doesn't always guarantee a result. I want this locationsMap() to be populated in all cases so that my result is consistent. Also, please don't change the signature of any method as the map is populated using redis cache value in my project, here I have given dummy hardcoded values so that anyone can execute this in his system.

The main issue is that the setCountry sometimes is able to set the value and sometimes its not due to the reactive nature of the code.

```
private Mono<Map<String,String>> locationsMap(){
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("DK", "Denmark");
        map.put("UK", "United Kingdom");
        return Mono.just(map);
    }

private void generateComplianceResponse(BOLCompliance complianceResponse) {
        // locationsMap().subscribe();
        locationsMap().flatMap(entry -> {
            Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> set = entry.entrySet();
            set.forEach(e -> {
                if (complianceResponse.getCompliancePort().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase(e.getKey())) {
                    complianceResponse.setCountry(e.getValue());
                }
            });
            return Mono.just(complianceResponse);
        }).subscribe();
    }


public class BOLCompliance {
    private String complianceType;
    private String compliancePort;
    private String country;
    private String lastSubmittedDate;
    private String deadlineTimestamp;
}

private Mono<BOLCompliance> createComplianceResponseMono(Compliance compliance, BillOfLadingResponse bol) {
        Mono<String> deadlineTS = portCallServiceCaller.getDeadlineTSByComplianceId(compliance.getComplianceId());

        return deadlineTS.flatMap(deadline -> {
            BOLCompliance complianceResponse = new BOLCompliance();
            if (compliance.getComplianceId() != null)
                complianceResponse.setDeadlineTimestamp(deadline);
            else
                complianceResponse.setDeadlineTimestamp(compliance.getSubmissionDeadline());
            complianceResponse.setCompliancePort(compliance.getCompliancePort());
            complianceResponse.setComplianceType(compliance.getComplianceType());
            complianceResponse.setLastSubmittedDate(
                    compliance.getLastSubmittedDate() != null ? compliance.getLastSubmittedDate().toString() : null);
            if (null != compliance.getBillOfLadings())
                compliance.getBillOfLadings().parallelStream()
                        .filter(billoflading -> billoflading.getBolNumber().equals(bol.getBolNumber()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()).parallelStream()
                        .forEach(bill -> generateComplianceResponse(complianceResponse, bill));
            return Mono.just(complianceResponse);
        });
    }
```

Comment: You need to give more context for your code. Where is generateComplianceResponse called from? If you need the output from reactive code then you should return a Mono.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi I have provided the complete code, please check now, I'm calling generateComplianceResponse() in the second last line of createComplianceResponseMono().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over Mono<Map<String, String>> and get the desired object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69986044/iterating-over-monomapstring-string-and-get-the-desired-object)

Comment: I have posted answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the consistent result with block().
But I remember in the past, this block() used to give error: block()/blockfirst()/blocklast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread
But for this piece of code its not giving any

```
    private void generateComplianceResponse(BOLCompliance complianceResponse, BOLReference bill) {
        complianceResponse.setStatus(bill.getStatus()!=null?bill.getStatus():null);
        complianceResponse.setErrorDetails(bill.getErrorDetails());
        getCustomsStatus(complianceResponse, bill);
        getComplianceCountry(complianceResponse).block();
    }
    
    private Mono<BOLCompliance> getComplianceCountry(BOLCompliance complianceResponse) {
        
        return locationMap().flatMap(entry -> {
        
        Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> set = entry.entrySet();
         set.forEach(e -> {
                if (complianceResponse.getCompliancePort().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase(e.getKey())) {
                    complianceResponse.setCountry(e.getValue());
                }
            });
            return Mono.just(complianceResponse);
        });
    }
```